# Why am I getting a segmentation fault here (C)

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I keep getting a segmentation fault in the line array[j]=array[j]+1.
I've included the portion of the main function used to call "mode", function which is the one I'm having trouble with. The program is supposed to take user input in the form of a string. Depending on what the string says the function does different things. For input "mode" it takes an array from the user and then finds the mode, or number that appears most often. The program may not be the cleanest or most efficient, but I just need it to work. Thank you for any help.

```
int mode(int input[]){
int array[30]={0},i=0,j=0,i2=0,j2=0;

while (input[i]!='\0'){
    j=input[i];
    array[j]=array[j]+1;
    i++;
    }

while (array[i2]!='\0'){
    if (array[i2]>j2){
        j2=array[i2];
        i2++;
    }
    else{
    i2++;
    }
}
return j2;
}


int main(){
char function_called[7];
int nums_for_mode[50],num_for_primes;
int num1,den1,num2,den2;


printf("Please choose a function (mode, primes, or fradd): ");
scanf("%s",&function_called);

if(strcmp(function_called, "mode")==0){
printf("\nPlease provide numbers between 1 and 30: ");
scanf("%i",&nums_for_mode);
printf("\nThe mode is %i\n",mode(nums_for_mode));
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: How many `char` elements do you think are needed to hold the string "primes" ? Hint: its *more* than 6.

Comment: _scanf("%i",&nums_for_mode)_ looks suspect. your scanning an integer into an address to an address to an int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nums_for_mode` is uninitialized, and you don't terminate it either.

Near the top of main, set each member of nums_form_mode to 0:

```
    for(int a = 0; a < 50; a++)
            nums_for_mode[a] = 0;
```

or, initialize it with ={0} at the declaration point. Fixing this will stop your segfault, but the program is still wrong:

- You should also get the numbers in a loop, currently, your program only actually receives one number.
- array[30] will be easy to overflow, including if you enter 30. You should make it one longer at least, and also check that the input actually is in range when reading it.
- The function_called buffer is too small and prone to overflow, you should limit the size of input in the call to scanf.
- this line: `while (array[i2]!='\0')` doesn't make much logical sense, it will terminate early without actually checking over the input.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. I'm working on it now. I'm taking my first programming course, so I make a lot of little mistakes. Again, thanks for the help!

Comment: So why doesn't while (array[i2]!='\0') work and how would I terminate the loops?

Comment: That's checking the value, you should be counting the length. Since that array is 30 items long, you should check all thirty items by doing `for(int place = 0; place < 30; place++) { /* check array[place] */` and return the maximum value you find in there.